# JavaScript Redirection

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

Here is the code I have,

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/uploads/"+<? $name ?>+"/output.txt";
    setTimeout("top.location.href = url",1000);
</script>
```

`$name` is a `PHP` variable which has the name of which directory I'm trying to redirect to.

Needless to say, it isn't working.  What's wrong with it?  I don't know a lot about `javascript` so I probably did something stupid

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your mixing PHP with JavaScript, it's always advisable to check the output being sent to the browser: right click on your website and **click view source!**

JavaScript doesn't care whether the content being sent to it is static HTML, from a Database or generated by PHP. If its in the output, it'll parse it.

If you'd have done that, you'd notice that your not `echo`'ing the `$name` variable.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/uploads/"+<? echo $name ?>+"/output.txt";
    setTimeout("top.location.href = url",1000);
</script>
```

But that'd give you

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/uploads/"+ foo +"/output.txt";
    setTimeout("top.location.href = url",1000);
</script>
```

Which isn't valid JavaScript, as `foo` is now a JS variable, not a string.

So you should have:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/uploads/<? echo $name ?>/output.txt";
    setTimeout("top.location.href = url",1000);
</script>
```

Furthermore, passing a string to `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) is not recommend; for the same reasons against using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!), so you should end up with something like this instead:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/uploads/<? echo $name ?>/output.txt";
    setTimeout(function () {
        top.location.href = url
    },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: pass a function not string though to setTimeout? but +1 on the string concatenation fix :)

Comment: Since you are using short tags anyway, `<?= ... ?>` is slightly shorter than `<? echo ... ?>`.

Answer (score 5):

Pass a function, not a string, to `setTimeout`.

```
var url = "http://localhost:8888/uploads/<?= $name ?>/output.txt";
setTimeout(function ()
{
    top.location.href = url;
}, 1000);
```

I am assuming that the `$name` is properly filled in by PHP.

Comment: $name isn't. OP needs to use <?=$name?> or <?php echo $name; ?>, but +1 for passing a function

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { top.location.href = url; }, 1000);
```

Comment: Don't forget the fact that OP hasn't even echo'd :)

Comment: I'm just responding to the OP's part of not knowing JavaScript.  You shouldn't pass a string to `setTimeout`.  I figured they'd know their PHP, as that wasn't a concern for them.  I don't know PHP to help them with that.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8888/uploads/"+<? $name ?>+"/output.txt";
setTimeout(function() {
    top.location.href = url;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php echo "var url = 'http://localhost:8888/uploads/$name/output.txt'";  ?>
```

Remove pluses and braces - just put variable in url.
Also use Firebug to troubleshoot your JS code: http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use 'echo' or the slightly unreadable php short code `<?=` to echo out a variable.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/uploads/<?php echo $name; ?>/output.txt";
    setTimeout(function(){
        top.location = url;
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

I know I've created another closure, but feel it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
window.location.href = url
```

Comment: Not if it's in a frameset. In any case, `window.location` works fine, you don't need to directly access the 'href' property.